# android onActivityResult vs getIntent

Tags: android, android-intent

Both `onActivityResult` and `getIntent` receives intent from other activities.

when one is used over another?

I think onActivityResult is called after I call startActivityForResult to receive a result.

I guess then `getIntent` is used to receive intent which was sent by someone other than me.  Is it correct?

Below is my understanding how it's used, wonder if the understanding is correct.

- I register to listen to certain intents (probably in manifest)
- when registered intents get delivered, a responsible activity resumes (or gets created)
- getIntent should generally be placed in `onResume` to check the intent
- one should dispose the used intent by removing whatever data inside the intent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think onActivityResult is called after I call startActivityForResult
>   to receive a result.

on `onActivityResult` is called when you `finish()` the Activity that you started with `startActivityForResult`. You can provide an `Intent` to `setResult`, which you will get back as part of `onActivityResult`

> I guess then getIntent is used to receive intent which was sent by
>   someone other than me. Is it correct?

`getIntent()` returns the intent that started the current `Activity`

Comment: Suppose an activity is resumed because another activity just popped off, the resumed activity calls `getIntent()`, the resumed activity calls `getIntent()` and it gets intent that originally created the activity?  Can you be more specific about  the `intent that started the current Activity`?

Comment: Yes exactly. getIntent returns always the intent that originally started the Activity.